# Compile application with FIPS capable openssl

Tags: c, openssl

Makefile:

```
OPENSSLDIR = /usr/local/ssl/fips­2.0
OPENSSL_INCLUDEDIR = /root/poc/openssl-1.0.2r/include/
FIPSMODULE = $(OPENSSLDIR)/lib/fipscanister.o
CC = /usr/bin/gcc

FIPSLD_CC = $(CC)
FIPSLD = /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld
CC = $(FIPSLD)

OBJS = poc.o
LIBCRYPTO = /root/poc/openssl-1.0.2r/libcrypto.a
LIBSSL = /root/poc/openssl-1.0.2r/libssl.a

libfoo.so:
        env FIPSLD_CC=/usr/bin/gcc $(FIPSLD) -fPIC -shared -o libfoo.so foo.c $(LIBCRYPTO) $(LIBSSL) # Working

poc.o:
        /usr/bin/gcc -I$(OPENSSL_INCLUDEDIR) -Wall -c poc.c

POC: libfoo.so $(OBJS)
        env FIPSLD_CC=/usr/bin/gcc $(FIPSLD) $(OBJS) $(LIBCRYPTO) $(LIBSSL) -L/root/poc -lfoo -ldl -o POC #working
        ***#/usr/bin/gcc $(OBJS) -L/root/poc -lfoo -ldl -o POC #notworking
        #env FIPSLD_CC=/usr/bin/gcc $(FIPSLD) $(OBJS) -L/root/poc -lfoo -ldl -o POC #notworking***
```

foo.c : Code for setting the fips mode ON, This will be a shared library for other applications.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int foo_func()
{
    int rc, mode;

    mode = FIPS_mode();
    if(mode == 0)
    {
        rc = FIPS_mode_set(1);  //Enable fips mode
        if(rc == 0) {
            printf("Failed to enable FIPS mode, ");
            printf("%s\n",ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(),NULL));
        } else {
            printf("Enabled FIPS mode");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Already in FIPS mode");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

poc.c: Application using the libfoo.so for setting fips mode ON.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    foo_func();  //Call function of foo.so library.
    return 0;
}
```

I want to make the #notwoking to be #working. Because i don't want to use the openssl libs to be compiled with POC application. Without that i am not able to set the FIPS mode.

How can i link openssl libs to just the shared library(libfoo.so) and compile my application (POC) with the libfoo.so and set the FIPS mode successfully.

Comment: Might be helpful to add the keywords "FIPS" and "OpenSSL" to the title.

Can you also include the output of the linker in both #working and #notworking cases?

Can you check if the FIPS symbols are present in the resulting libfoo.so?

Comment: Linker does not give any error, when we execute the binary FIPS_mode_set give the error ("fingerprint does not match nonpic relocated"). Yes, symbols are present in libfoo.so